# Native calls from CCXWebView in cocos2d-js project

Tags: webview, spidermonkey, cocos2d-html5, cocos2d-js

1. I have a game written in coco2d-js v3.0, which I've embedded it into a web page.
2. Now in order to run this web page (with my game in it) on a mobile device I need to use CCXWebView (or kind of).

Can I still got the native calls for a game even through the CCXWebView?

1) is done, but I'm still confused about 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you.  They will add ios native call in their next release.

https://github.com/chukong/cocos-docs/blob/master/manual/framework/html5/v3/reflection/en.md